# Unable to modifiy Active Directory from Test/Production servers

Tags: active-directory

OK since I am in a holding pattern on this issue perhaps someone has seen these symptoms and can provide some sage advice.  (Note: I have learned only enough Active Directory information to build this feature and I only have read access to the Active Directory.)

I updated the company intranet to allow the automatic entry/modification of employee phone/address information; it uses a web service to connect to the company Active Directory so I can call it from multiple locations in the main application.

The AD has two domains (A and B) in the same forest.  Each domain has an ‘ADS update user’ group and an ‘ADSupdate’ account (which belongs to ‘ADS update user’).

Problem:  Entries in Domain A update fine for Local Development Servers, Test Servers, and Production Servers.  Entries in Domain B update only when run from Local Development Servers.  When you run the same code (verified multiple times) on either Test or Production you get a (General access denied error).

The domain name is stored in the employee record so the exact same code is called for all employees.

All Local Development Servers, Test, and Production servers reside in Domain A.

This has the Active Directory Admin for Domain B stumped and to be honest I am thankful that the Local Development Servers are able to update the Active Directory entries in domain B.  It proves that the code works at least in one location

I have looked at machine permissions, permissions on the group and user, and IIS and I can spot no significant differences.
Any help would be appreciated…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not caused by any code changes.  The Production and Test servers were upgraded and run a newer version of IIS (6.0).  The newer version of IIS will not work accross Active Directory domains.

My development machine is running the older version of IIS (5.1)

This explains why everthing was working last year and then suddenly stopped working.  There are so few employees in the other domain that it was not immediatly noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Is integrated authentication enabled on any of the web service applications?

Are the production application on domain A installed on a domain controller?

Does the updates from the development workstation work when you call the web service from a remote machine?